# Moderation strike: how is the discussion going between the moderators and Stack Overflow, Inc?

Tags: discussion, moderation-strike

It has been some time since the strike began; are there any news? I can find some stats here about queues, etc. but I have no information regarding the actual position of the two sides.

Have there been any changes / steps forward?

Answer (score 184, accepted):

Updates are generally posted in the Discord server that is currently serving as the organization hub for the strike. Since not everyone is in the Discord server, updates are now being copied to [a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/390704/294691) on Meta.SE.

This was the most recent that I shared, as one of the representatives, on the 26th of June:

> **Negotiation updates**: We have made significant progress in many of the issues involved in this strike. During the course of negotiations, the initial negotiator from Stack has recused himself from negotiations, citing the portrayal of his statements here in the Meta server, indicating they create an unsafe environment for him to continue negotiations. In light of this, Philippe has taken over as the primary representative from Stack Exchange, Inc.'s side. Unfortunately, due to entirely justified non-public reasons, further progress in negotiations will be rather slower over the next couple of days.
> While we wait for that progress to resume, Stack is internally drafting a proposal to present to the community representatives that covers the progress we have made so far. In the same vein, I'd like to share the progress we've made on various demands and issues so far, and ensure that the community is on board with the steps we're taking.
>
> **Demand:** The prohibition on moderating GPT content must be retracted.
> **Progress:** We have tentatively established a broader replacement interim policy, that will allow moderators much more room to remove AI content (although not to the same extent as before). This policy will go into effect upon release, replacing the current private policy. More permanent standards will be established by a working group of moderators and users who are active in removing gen-AI content, in a private Stack Overflow for Teams instance. Information on how to be invited to the Team will be available when we move along a little further in the process.
> The replacement policy will be based on "strong" and "weak" heuristics, with guidelines on removing based on which heuristics are present. Moderator judgement calls will still be required. These standards will be open to revision as technology changes and data is gathered on identifying AI-generated content.
>
> **Demand:** The private policy on GPT content that was issued to moderators must be revealed publicly.
> **Progress:** Stack has agreed to release it publicly on Meta. However, it will be released with a disclaimer (as-yet unwritten) stating that they do not plan on releasing all moderator policy guidance publicly, but are doing so in this case. This disclaimer will have to be approved by reps before it's posted. This will be released after the new interim policy goes into effect.
>
> **Demand:** The data dumps must be re-enabled, and SEDE and API access guaranteed.
> **Progress:** We have reached the agreement below. This commitment will be announced publicly by Stack Exchange, Inc. (I don't know exactly when).
> **Agreement:** Stack Exchange, Inc. commits to: Continuing to operate the data dumps; continuing to provide Stack Exchange Data Explorer access; and continuing to provide API access. All of these will remain operational and free of charge for individual network users, for the foreseeable, long-term future.  For companies and organizations, other terms may apply.
>
> **Demand:** Stack Exchange, Inc. must communicate, gather feedback, and act on that feedback before making major policy or software changes to the public platform.
> **Progress:** The representatives from Stack Exchange, Inc. have indicated that they are willing to add a stipulation that binding policy changes (i.e. anything tagged [moderator-agreement-policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/moderator-agreement-policy)) go through a mandatory seven-day review period by moderators. This is not yet finalized, and we have not yet reached a conclusion on software changes.
> Stack has also indicated that toxicity in staff/mod communication is a sticking point in increasing this interaction, particularly in the Teachers' Lounge. While I disputed many of the examples that were brought, some examples were brought that did cross the line. I've handled those cases, and I will be speaking to the other Teachers' Lounge elected moderators about making sure this is addressed more consistently in the future.
>
> **Issue:** Stack Exchange, Inc.'s data analysis is flawed.
> **Progress:** The representatives from Stack have indicated that their experience on the network during the course of the strike has shown that their internal estimates were inaccurate, although not yet convinced that they are as inaccurate as we (the moderators and community) believe. They are not willing to retract the policy change based on that alone.
>
> **Issue:** Moderators were not spoken to by CMs when their actions were in doubt.
> **Progress:** Stack has stated that their internal guidance was to almost never consult with moderators about actions taken, due to a belief that moderators want to moderate and are not interested in justifying their actions to staff. We have established that the vast majority of moderators would welcome any questions about their actions and be more than willing to explain - or, even better, to train CMs in how to figure out why those actions were taken. Stack Exchange Inc. will revise their internal guidance to reflect this.
>
> **Issue:** Stack Exchange, Inc. made inappropriate comments to the press.
> **Progress:** We are debating this issue and have not yet reached a conclusion. Stack is so far unwilling to agree to a blanket policy of "no comment" when asked for comment on anything involving moderators; we are considering what our options are here. Stack Exchange, Inc. would like to keep open the option of commenting on general moderator actions not taken by an individual; the representatives are pushing for Stack to refrain commenting even about groups of moderators. Stack has also indicated that they think it would be unfair for the company to be bound to not comment while individual moderators are free to comment, citing my own personal statements to the press. I've reminded them that they are a billion-dollar company, while we are a group of volunteers.
>
> **Issue:** There is no recourse if Stack Exchange, Inc. breaks the Moderator Agreement.
> **Progress:** Frankly, there's been no progress. It was floated that a group such as the Moderator Council should have the authority to rule that an action taken by Stack Exchange, Inc. broke the Agreement, and is so rendered null and void; however, the Mod Council is currently defunct and is unlikely to be revived. We have not resolved this to any degree; suggestions are welcome.

Comment: I completely missed your post with the regular updates. Now I'm following that

Comment: "Stack Exchange, Inc. must communicate, gather feedback, and act on that feedback before making major policy or software changes to the public platform." - not quite sure if that means _public_ communication or just speaking to mods, but whatever promise they make here will be enthusiastically broken faster than you can write an angry meta post anyways. We were promised lots of times that next time proper procedures would be followed as response to an outrage over uncommunicated changes. Instead, this got consistently worse over the years, so I don't expect any significant change here.

Comment: @l4mpi - Both public and mod communication. It's looking likely that any major policy changes will be required by the mod agreement (so _contractually_ obligated) to go through a _minimum_ seven-day review period by moderators. While that's the bare minimum, we're also pushing for much more general interaction and feedback gathering.

Comment: The contrast of the voting buttons is much better 8-))

Comment: @Mithical and as you wrote yourself, "There is no recourse if Stack Exchange, Inc. breaks the Moderator Agreement" and there's currently no path forward for that issue, so "contractually obligated" doesn't seem to carry much weight. Also, you only mention policy changes - for software  changes I can never see this happen, if the CEO wants the next hype thing in production yesterday, they're going to inform the community after the fact.

Comment: We _are_ workshopping some potential ways to slap Stack's wrist if they do violate the agreement, @l4mpi; hopefully I'll be able to share some progress soon.

Comment: @nvoigt:  I'm a passer-by in there and I don't think we're talking on the level of bodily harm or anything like that that would give cause to escalate to some enforcement body.  But honestly, it is what it is and we're movin' forward with the next rep.

Comment: @nvoigt in 2023 safe == no feelings hurt, so yea, a lot of un-safeness

Comment: Glad to see some progress, but I can't help but feel that without recourse if Stack Exchange, Inc. breaks the Moderator Agreement the entire thing may not be worth the pixels it is displayed with. We have seen that SE changes their mind on agreements and promises when it suits them, and I don't trust them not to continue to do so in the future. **"I am altering the Deal, pray I don't alter it any further."** is not a basis for a good relationship.

Comment: "no recourse if Stack Exchange, Inc. breaks the Moderator Agreement." The nuclear option is to put it to the vote on meta stack exchange. I'd rather have a much better choice than that one.

Comment: @nvoigt: I generated the interpretation that being the negotiator was creating an unsafe work environment on corporate side.

Comment: @Joshua how do you have a fair vote when you don't control the voting platform?